# Flutter web : Failed to load resource: net::ERR_NAME_NOT_RESOLVED

Tags: flutter, flutter-web

Flutter web is just showing **empty** white page in chrome and I get `Failed to load resource: net::ERR_NAME_NOT_RESOLVED` in **console** of chrome by using inpect .It's reproducible even with flutter counter app on web.

I have  `Flutter Channel stable 2.0.2`, `and Android Studio (version 4.1.0)`.
It's working fine in emulator.
how can I solve the problem?
[image: error image]

I tried following commands in cmd but still have problem :

```
ipconfig /flushdns
ipconfig /renew
ipconfig /registerdns
```

Comment: Please [edit] your question to add a [mre].

Comment: there is no error so I can not add any reproducible code.

Comment: `net::ERR_NAME_NOT_RESOLVED` is a DNS error. If you show us your code, maybe we can help you figure out what's going on.

Comment: I added some code.

Comment: And what is the base URL?

Comment: It is `192.168.56.1:81` it's visible in code. I'm using xampp and It's localhost on port 81

Comment: Whoops, you’re right. Does XAMPP bind to all interfaces instead of just localhost? What happens when you go to 192.168.56.1:81?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you be connected to internet, It will work and no error will occur But This error occurs in flutter web in **Offline** mode because CanvasKit is not automatically bundled for **offline** development.

To make it work **offline** there are two ways:

1- the easy way ( run this code in terminal ):

```
flutter run -d chrome --web-renderer html
```

2- the second way ( instructions are mentioned by flutter [team](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/78235#) ):

- Download (or build) CanvasKit anywhere under the web/ directory of
  your project.
- Follow [these instructions](https://github.com/flutter/engine/blob/7b2db6dbe1c49a8004ff865607988eec36868ccc/lib/web_ui/lib/src/engine/canvaskit/initialization.dart#L51) and specify FLUTTER_WEB_CANVASKIT_URL to
  point to `/path/to/bundled/canvaskit/` (if it's in the root of web/
  then I think it's just `/`).
- Include all the necessary fonts in your pubspec.yaml ([instructions](https://flutter.dev/docs/cookbook/design/fonts))

**Notes for working offline in release mode:**

In release mode, in order to make app work offline, after releasing app with command `flutter build web`, go to `index.html` file in `build/web` then add this code to the script tag:

```
  <script>
    window.flutterConfiguration = {
    canvasKitBaseUrl: "/canvaskit/"
  };

...
```

Comment: What is the link to download the complete CanvasKit folder? and from where we define and set FLUTTER_WEB_CANVASKIT_URL environment variable? Answers to these questions are not in the instructions. This may help: https://developer.school/tutorials/how-to-use-environment-variables-with-flutter-dotenv

Answer (score 0):

I ran into this problem when serving the app not from the root of my webserver.
I had to specify the `<base>` tag in *web/index.html*, then it worked for me.

Comment: `<base href="/">` in index.html already exists.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the Makefile for it

```
webrun:
    wasmLocation="$(shell grep canvaskit-wasm build/web/main.dart.js | sed -e 's/.*https/https/' | sed -e 's/\/bin.*/\/bin/' | uniq)"; \
    curl -o ./web/canvaskit.js "$$wasmLocation/canvaskit.js"; \
    curl -o ./web/canvaskit.wasm "$$wasmLocation/canvaskit.wasm"; \
    flutter run -d chrome --release --web-renderer=canvaskit --dart-define=FLUTTER_WEB_CANVASKIT_URL=./
```